# what is meant by $ f ∈ C^{2}[a, b] ?$

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives, notation, definition

What is the meaning of $ f ∈ C^{2}[a, b]   ?$
I think it says that $f$ is twice differential on $[a,b]$, isn't it?

Comment: A bit more than that, it's twice differentiable and the second derivative is continuous.

Comment: Thank you everybody for quick and reliable answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, if $f\in C^k,$ then the derivatives $f',\ f'',\ \dots,\ f^{(k)}$ exist and are continuous. Here is the [reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoothness#Differentiability_classes).

Comment: Thanks, the reference did the job!

Comment: No problem! Glad it helped.

Answer (score 4):

It means that $f^{\prime\prime}$ is continuous on $[a,b]$.

Answer (score 1):

$f$ is twice differentiable on $\left [a, b \right]$ and $f''$ is continuous on $\left [a,b \right]$. The derivatives at the boundaries are to be understood in the sense of one-sided derivatives.